# Collect user input to customize Sheet Names in VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, input

I have a couple macros that pull in two sheets to a single workbook from different workbooks in a file and compare the two sheets row by row for differences. The problem is that whenever I'm comparing new pairs of sheets I have to change all the sheet references in the VBA code. Is there a way to add an input or message box asking for the two new names of the sheets? For example one box would pop up and say, "Please enter the original sheet name" and another that would pop up and say, "Please enter the new sheet name." Additionally, is there a way to combine theses macros to as few as possible?

```
Sub GetSourceSheets()
'This macro will loop through excel files
'in a location and copy the their worksheets into the current workbook.
'Instructions: Replace the file path, which starts on the 8th line, with a file path to the folder
'that contains the two vendor site lists that you wish to compare.
'!!!! Do not for get to place the back slash (\) at the end of the file path. !!!! End of Instructions
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Path = "C:\Users\turner\Desktop\Excel_Con\Kevin\NA_Vendor\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub RunCompare()
'Instructions: Replace North_American_Old with the original vendor site list sheet name and
'replace North_American_New with the new vendor site list sheet name you wish
'to compare to the original vendor site list sheet.
'!!!!! Keep sheet names enclosed in quotations !!!! End of Instructions
Call compareSheets("North_America_Old", "North_America_New")

End Sub


Sub compareSheets(shtNorth_America_Old As String, shtNorth_America_New As String)
'Instructions: Replace North_American_Old with the original vendor site list sheet name and
'replace North_American_New with the new vendor site list sheet name you wish
'to compare to the original vendor site list sheet.
'!!!!! Keep sheet names enclosed in quotations and remember to keep "sht" at the beginning of the sheet name!!!!
'End of Instructions
Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

'For each cell in sheet2 that is not the same in Sheet1, color it yellow
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtNorth_America_New).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtNorth_America_Old).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

        mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

'Display a message box to demonstrate the differences
MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtNorth_America_New).Select

End Sub
```

Compare Macros with Input Boxes

```
Sub RunCompare()

Dim sht1 As String
Dim sht2 As String

sht1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the first sheet name")
sht2 = Application.InputBox("Enter the second sheet name")
Call compareSheets("sht1", "sht2")

End Sub


Sub compareSheets(sht1 As String, sht2 As String)

Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

'For each cell in sheet2 that is not the same in Sheet1, color it yellow
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sht2).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sht1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

        mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

'Display a message box to demonstrate the differences
MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht2).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim result as Variant` and `result = Application.Inputbox(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still not sure how associate the input box to the code representing the original sheet or the sheet i want to compare with the original sheet.

Comment: `Dim North_America_Old as Variant` `and North_America_Old = Application.Inputbox("Enter Old Sheet Name")`. Something like that perhaps?

Comment: I get a subscript out of range at `For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtNorth_America_New).UsedRange` when I incorporate the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inputbox:

```
Dim sht1 as String
Dim sht2 as String

sht1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the first sheet name")
sht2 = Application.InputBox("Enter the second sheet name")
```

But with this approach, you need to trap errors: if the user has misseplled the worksheet name, etc., or if they cancel out of the input box, etc.

**Alternatively,** a UserForm with ListBox or ComboBox to choose worksheets.  Again, you'll need to do some validation (user can't select the same sheet in both lists, etc.) but I will leave the actual use-case for you to work out.

Create a user form with two comboboxes and a command button.

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem ws.Name
Next

End Sub
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call compareSheets(ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox2.Value)
End Sub
```

**Alternatively,** just select the two worksheets you want to compare, and do something like this:

```
Sub RunCompare()
    Dim selSheets as Sheets
    Set selSheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    If selSheets.Count = 2 Then
        Call CompareSheets(selSheets(1).Name, selSheets(2).Name)
    Else:
        MsgBox "Please select TWO sheets to compare", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much. The last alternative works well. Would the input box approach code need to be incorporated into the "RunCompare," the "compareSheets" macro or both?  How could the input box approach code be incorporated?

Comment: Yes, you would incorporate the inputbox method in `RunCompare` procedure.  Put those 4 lines before `Call compareSheets`, then change the line `Call compareSheets(sht1, sht2)`.

Comment: Thanks again @DavidZemens. After incorporating the input box code and changing all of the "North_America_Old" to "sht1" and "North_America_Old" to "sht2" in the compareSheets macro, I get a run time error # 9 at this line of code, `For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtsht2).UsedRange` in the compareSheets macro.

Comment: Typo?  What is `shtsht2`? Shouldn't it be `sht2`?

Comment: I've used both methods and I still get a run time error # 9 at thie line of code. I've edited my original question above to include the macros, under "Compare Macros with Input Boxes," with shtsht2 and shtsht1 as sht2 and sht1. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes. Your variables **are** `sht1` and `sht2`. These *represent* the worksheets by name. Do **NOT** enclose the variable name in quotation marks (you did `"sht1", "sht2"`). Doing so makes them *not* variables, but rather literal strings, and since there is no worksheet named "sht2", this raises an error (expectedly).